Condition for $\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\log \left(1-x^k\right)-\log (1-x)\right)$?
Could someone confirm/prove that the following limit evaluates to $0$ for the condition $\Re(k)>0$?
$$\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\log \left(1-x^k\right)-\log (1-x)\right)$$
WolframAlpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BLog%5B1+-+x%5Ek%5D+-+Log%5B1+-+x%5D%2C+x+-%3E+0%2C+Direction+-%3E+-1%5D) gives the condition $1/2 < k < 1$, but it appears to me that the condition could be broadened to $\Re(k)>0$.

Wolfram is drunk. I haven't proved it for all Re(k)>0, but if you choose $k$ to be any positive integer, you can factor $(1-x^{k})=-(x^{k}-1)=-(x-1)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\dots+1)$, which means your limit looks like:
$\log(x^{k-1}+\dots+1) + \log(1-x) -\log(1-x) = \log(x^{k-1}+\dots+1)$
Which is quite obviously $0$. So wolframs bound for $k$ is nonsense already. Should I manage to compute this for any $k$, I will post a complete answer.

@Almeida if $k$ is a positive integer, the limit is not an indeterminate form, it's $\log 1-\log 1=0$. I don't understand why there's a need to factor the expression

You're right. Im silly.

I managed to coach wolfram into computing the limit for $k=1+i$, so it agrees that it's other asnwer can't possibly be right: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BLog%5B1+-+x%5E%281%2Bi%29%5D+-+Log%5B1+-+x%5D%2C+x+-%3E+0%5D

And apparently, it will even give out other nonsense answers if you change the letter you use for the variable (here I use $z$ instead of $k$ and it spits out $1<z<2$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BLog%5B1+-+x%5Ez%5D+-+Log%5B1+-+x%5D%2C+x+-%3E+0%2C+Direction-%3E-1%5D

I don't get the issue here. As Sine of the Time called out, for $x\to 0^{+}$, and real $k>0$, the limit is not even a indeterminate form. Since $\log$ is a continous function, one can simply re-write as:
$$\log\left(\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} 1-x^{k}\right) - \log\left(\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} 1-x\right)$$
The right limit is clearly just $0$. The left limit is slightly trickier. For any real $k>0$, it's obvious it's also $0$, as $x^{a}\to 0$ for any real $a>0$. If we accept complex $k$, it adds a new layer, but that is also easy to bypass. One simply needs to let $k=a+ib$ and observe that:
$$\vert x^{k} \vert = \vert x^{a} \vert \cdot \vert e^{b\ln{x}i} \vert = \vert x^{a} \vert$$
So, clearly, for $Re(k)>0$, we have that $x^{k} \to 0$ as well. Meaning our limit is just $0-0$ and we are done.

This proof looks complete and correct to me. Thanks!

Your limit is basically
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}-x^k\frac{\log{(1-x^k)}}{-x^k}+x\frac{\log{(1-x)}}{-x}$$
Now $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$
Making the limit $$=-x^k+x=0$$
I don't understand why there is a restriction for $k$. As Almeida said, $k$ can already be extended to all positive integers. This actually works for all $k>0$
Reason for $k>0$ is that as $x\to 0$, negative $k$ upon $x$ would lead to $1-x^k<0$, but domain of logarithm function is always positive.
